# Get variable from spinbox (Python)

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

```
finestra = Tk()
var = IntVar() #i did the same with the others variable except for the spin
cpu = Label(text="Seleziona la generazione del tuo processore:").pack()
core = Radiobutton(finestra,text="Core",value=1, variable=var)
core.pack()
x = Radiobutton(finestra,text="2 duo/ 2 quad",value=5/3, variable=var)
x.pack()


serie = Label(text="Seleziona il tuo processore:").pack()
i3 = Radiobutton(finestra,text="i3 xxxx/Pentium",value=51, variable=ivar)
i3.pack()
i5 = Radiobutton(finestra,text="i5 xxxx",value=65, variable=ivar)
i5.pack()
i7 = Radiobutton(finestra,text="i7 xxxx",value=75, variable=ivar)
i7.pack()

brand = Label(text="Seleziona la tua scheda video:").pack()
Radiobutton(finestra,text="GTX 1050", value=70,variable=gvar).pack()
Radiobutton(finestra,text="GTX 1050ti", value=75,variable=gvar).pack()

Label(text="Seleziona il numero di banchi di RAM e il loro quantitativo")
ram = Spinbox(finestra, from_=1, to=4).pack()

def callback(*args):
    result.set(var.get()*ivar.get()+gvar.get()+ram.get())

var.trace("w", callback)
ivar.trace("w", callback)
gvar.trace("w",callback)

result = StringVar()

tdp = Label(textvariable=result).pack()

finestra.mainloop()
```

Well, I want that when I insert 1 or ... 4 in the spinbox, this value is summed with gvar and with the product of ivar and var. 
I have also another question. In the 6th row there is a fraction, but when  I run the program even though it doesn't give errors, it understand as if it were 5 (not 5/3). Can you explain me how can I use rational numbers? 
PS: sorry for my italian-english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed some things. ram = Spin....pack() does not return the spin object, but None. The 5/3 problem is that Python assumes integer division unless you put a decimal point on at least one of the arguments (5.0.3 works). This should get you going though.

```
from tkinter import *

finestra = Tk()
var = DoubleVar(value=5.0/3) #i did the same with the others variable except for the spin
ivar = IntVar(value=65)
gvar = IntVar(value=70)
spin = StringVar()
cpu = Label(text="Seleziona la generazione del tuo processore:").pack()
core = Radiobutton(finestra,text="Core",value=1, variable=var)
core.pack()
x = Radiobutton(finestra,text="2 duo/ 2 quad",value=5.0/3, variable=var)
x.pack()


serie = Label(text="Seleziona il tuo processore:").pack()
i3 = Radiobutton(finestra,text="i3 xxxx/Pentium",value=51, variable=ivar)
i3.pack()
i5 = Radiobutton(finestra,text="i5 xxxx",value=65, variable=ivar)
i5.pack()
i7 = Radiobutton(finestra,text="i7 xxxx",value=75, variable=ivar)
i7.pack()

brand = Label(text="Seleziona la tua scheda video:").pack()
Radiobutton(finestra,text="GTX 1050", value=70,variable=gvar).pack()
Radiobutton(finestra,text="GTX 1050ti", value=75,variable=gvar).pack()

Label(text="Seleziona il numero di banchi di RAM e il loro quantitativo")
ram = Spinbox(finestra, from_=1, to=4, textvariable=spin).pack()

def callback(*args):
    result.set(var.get()*ivar.get()+gvar.get()+int(spin.get()))

var.trace("w", callback)
ivar.trace("w", callback)
gvar.trace("w",callback)
spin.trace("w", callback)

result = StringVar(value='none')

Label(textvariable=result).pack()

finestra.mainloop()
```